# How to process paramerters in URL in slim framework?

Tags: php, slim

A simple REST GET call

```
http://localhost/root/student/11
```

can be handled via

```
 $data->get('/student/:id', 'getStudent');
```

I however have a want to send parametric data like because it solves my other problem in

```
 http://localhost/root/student?id=11
```

How can I process this data in SLim framework ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slim docs: [Request Variables](http://docs.slimframework.com/#Request-Variables).

Your example:

```
$app->get('/root/student', function() use ($app) {
    $id = $app->request()->get("id");
    //$id is '11' now
});
```